# convert string to time-format in R language

Tags: r, string, datetime-format

I have strings like this:

```
100
200
...
2300
```

how to transfer this to time format?

```
01:00:00
02:00:00
...
23:00:00
```

do I have to add 0 to the string?
I have tried

```
Data$Time <- formatC(Data$Time, digits = 6, flag = "0")
```

But it's not working

Comment: Can you be more specific than it's not working? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to do the formatting and then convert to `Time` with `as.ITime`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(sub("(..)", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d:00", v1)))
#[1] "01:00:00" "02:00:00" "23:00:00"
```

As @Claudio mentioned, if it is a vector of strings, replace the `%04d` with `%04s`

#### data

```
v1 <- c(100, 200, 2300)
```

Comment: Please note that the OP has a vector of strings, so I think it should be `as.ITime(sub("(..)", "\\1:", sprintf("%04s:00", v1)))`, and `v1 <- c("100", "200", "2300")`